# Run task on new ECS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-ecs

I'd like to run a new task on an ECS cluster when a new SNS message is published. For doing that, I have a Lambda function that runs the task. However, I don't want to have an instance always running, I'd like to have an empty cluster and run a new instance each time the lambda function is called (so the task is executed in the new instance), then, once the task is done, stop the instance again.
How could I achieve that behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your case sounds like a good candidate for AWS Batch - take a quick look

Comment: I'll take a look, thank you very much!